# Configuring permissions with Bastille

Tags: permissions, security, root, users

I was using **Bastille** to improve the security of my OS. To set this software properly, it ask you several questions related to security rules and you respond it (Y-N). I'm stuck at [this question](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1054731/) that I don't know if I should answer for `YES` or `NOT`.

---

**My users:**

When I installed Ubuntu I had create the A user (*admin*), then I was able to create another user, B (*standard*).

---

**Questions:**

1. The effects of this option will affect the two users (A & B) or just to B?
2. The user A there I'm using is the *admin* but not the `root`, right?
3. What are the differences (in terms of permissions) between the user A (*admin*) and the user B (*standard*)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reached the following conclusions by interpreting the information in the `/etc/passwd` file:

1. **Yes.** Because no one of both are the `root`.
2. **Correct.** The *admin* have not so much privileges as `root`.  Because the `UID` is different than zero (admin UID>0), the `root` is the only one this property.
3. The *admin* user has a high privilege level (like install software) and the *standard* user has low privilege (it can't install software on the system)

---

More information about the `/etc/passwd` file [here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passwd_%28file%29)